# Combine logical vectors to create non-logical vector

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have two logical vectors in a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(log1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), log2 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

I want to make a third column by combining these two. But this new column should not simply contain logical values. Instead, it should assign one of three values - "high", "outlier", or "normal" to the third column. "High" takes precedence, so the third column should show "high" and not "outlier" for row 5.

I guess it's possible to do this with using `if` and `else`, but I couldn't make it work using the following code:

```
df$new <- NA
if(df$log1 == TRUE){
  df$new <-  "high"
  } else if(df$log2 == TRUE) {
    df$new  <-  "outlier"
    } else {
      df$new  <-  "normal"
      }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `df$new <- ifelse(df$log1, "high",  ifelse(df$log2, "outlier", "normal"))` should work. Note when working with logicals, you dont need `x == TRUE` - R implicitly reads `if(x){...}` as "if x is TRUE, do ..." and `if(!x){...}` as "if x is FALSE, do ...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all about `ifelse` and its derivatives.

## base R

```r
ifelse(df$log1, "high", ifelse(df$log2, "outlier", "normal"))
# [1] "outlier" "normal" "high"   "normal" "high"
```

## dplyr

We can nest `dplyr::if_else`, but nesting generally encourages us to use `case_when`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    new1 = if_else(log1, "high", if_else(log2, "outlier", "normal")), 
    new2 = case_when(log1 ~ "high", log2 ~ "outlier", TRUE ~ "normal")
  )
#    log1  log2    new1    new2
# 1 FALSE  TRUE outlier outlier
# 2 FALSE FALSE  normal  normal
# 3  TRUE FALSE    high    high
# 4 FALSE FALSE  normal  normal
# 5  TRUE  TRUE    high    high
```

## data.table

Similarly, `fifelse` and `fcase`:

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, new1 := fifelse(log1, "high", fifelse(log2, "outlier", "normal"))
  ][, new2 := fcase(log1, "high", log2, "outlier", default = "normal")][]
#      log1   log2    new1    new2
#    <lgcl> <lgcl>  <char>  <char>
# 1:  FALSE   TRUE outlier outlier
# 2:  FALSE  FALSE  normal  normal
# 3:   TRUE  FALSE    high    high
# 4:  FALSE  FALSE  normal  normal
# 5:   TRUE   TRUE    high    high
```

Note that while `dplyr::case_when` above uses tilde-formulas as in `cond1 ~ value1, cond2 ~ value2`, the `fcase` variant uses alternating arguments, `cond1, value1, cond2, value2, ...)`.

Also, the `default=` argument works so long as it is a constant. If a dynamic default value (i.e., based on table contents) is desired, then one needs to have an all-true vector as in `fcase(..., rep(TRUE, .N), NEWVALUE)`.

Comment: I appreciate it ... I'm usually also very hesitant, I've found some edits on my answers in the past added takeaways that I did not say or intend, and it was a little annoying. Easily fixed, of course. Your edit was perfectly fine and encouraged. Thank you @jpsmith

Answer (score 5):

Try this without `if`/`else`:

```
df$new <- "normal"
df[df$log1, ]$new <- "high"
df[!df$log1 & df$log2, ]$new <- "outlier"

   log1  log2     new
1 FALSE  TRUE outlier
2 FALSE FALSE  normal
3  TRUE FALSE    high
4 FALSE FALSE  normal
5  TRUE  TRUE    high
```

**A dplyr solution:**
try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = ifelse(log1,
                      "high",
                      ifelse(log2,
                             "outlier",
                             "normal")  
  )
  )
```

Comment: This is a great alternative approach, and it works great! One suggestion: whenever I use this approach in my code, I always put the highest priority reassignment _last_. While the logic here is perfectly non-overlapping (and therefore no change with this data), in a more generalized sense where the logic may not be as perfectly complementary, having it last ensures it overrides any other value.

Answer (score 2):

Using indexing:

```
df$new <- with(df, c("normal", "outlier", "high", "high")[2L*log1 + log2 + 1L])
df
#>    log1  log2     new
#> 1 FALSE  TRUE outlier
#> 2 FALSE FALSE  normal
#> 3  TRUE FALSE    high
#> 4 FALSE FALSE  normal
#> 5  TRUE  TRUE    high
```

The `data.table` solutions pointed out by @r2evans are the fastest and most memory efficient. Indexing wins for base solutions.

```
f1 <- function(df) {
  within(df, new <- ifelse(log1, "high", ifelse(log2, "outlier", "normal")))
}

f2 <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      new = if_else(log1, "high", if_else(log2, "outlier", "normal")), 
    )
}

f3 <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      new = case_when(log1 ~ "high", log2 ~ "outlier", TRUE ~ "normal")
    )
}

f4 <- function(df) {
  setDT(df)[, new := fifelse(log1, "high", fifelse(log2, "outlier", "normal"))]
}

f5 <- function(df) {
  setDT(df)[, new := fcase(log1, "high", log2, "outlier", default = "normal")]
}

f6 <- function(df) {
  df$new <- "normal"
  df[df$log1, ]$new <- "high"
  df[!df$log1 & df$log2, ]$new <- "outlier"
  df
}

f7 <- function(df) {
  within(df, new <- c("normal", "outlier", "high", "high")[2L*log1 + log2 + 1L])
}
```

Benchmark:

```
df <- data.frame(log1 = sample(!0:1, 1e5, 1), log2 = sample(!0:1, 1e5, 1))

bench::mark(
  ifelse = f1(df),
  if_else = f2(df),
  case_when = f3(df),
  fifelse = f4(df),
  fcase = f5(df),
  subsetting = f6(df),
  indexing = f7(df),
  check = FALSE # mix of data.table and data.frame
)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 ifelse      40.32ms   41.9ms      24.0   10.32MB     12.0
#> 2 if_else      8.13ms   8.92ms     111.     9.95MB     33.0
#> 3 case_when    6.58ms   7.09ms     137.     7.36MB     45.7
#> 4 fifelse      1.68ms   2.01ms     483.     3.42MB     18.0
#> 5 fcase        1.45ms   1.57ms     618.      1.2MB     22.6
#> 6 subsetting   6.99ms    8.2ms     120.    10.85MB     59.9
#> 7 indexing     1.57ms   2.54ms     389.     4.27MB     50.9
```

Comment: Upvoted. I would also offer `bitwShiftL(as.integer(log1), 1L) + as.integer(log2)`

Comment: Or even `bitwOr(bitwShiftL(as.integer(T), 1L), as.integer(T))`